# Where do iOS Simulator screen recordings go?

Tags: ios, macos, ios-simulator

Sorry if this is obvious, but where do iOS Simulator screen recordings go? They are not on my Desktop.

I accidentally started a screen recording and it recorded for like an hour before I stopped it. I'd like to delete that file but I can't find any indication on where that video file is getting stored and Google has been no help.

Comment: for me it is saved to Desktop

Comment: "it recorded for like an hour" same! So I just quickly dragged the thumbnail preview thing to the trash.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to record a video in IOS Simulator.
Open File menu > Record Screen or ⌘ - command + R .

Simulator saves screenshot file on (logged-in user's) desktop and it's the default path.

To change the default path (with Xcode 9+), press and hold ⌥ the Option (alt) button from the keyboard, while you take a screenshot.

Or
Using Mac Keyboard: Press keys ⌥ Option + ⌘ + s altogether.
It will show a dialog with file storage options and also allows to set/change the default path.

Comment: none of these address finding the location of where screen video-recordings go.

Comment: when you  Press keys ⌥ Option + ⌘ + s altogether it will show you the last default location

Comment: For screenshots. Yes, all my screenshots go there, but no videos are there. It definitely seems to be successfully recording them. Unless it's not? Maybe it's a bug with the simulator

Comment: For me the videos appear on the desktop, but only after a very long time (several seconds with no feedback). They don't appear on the desktop if you touch the video and release it while it is next to the simulator. I wish I could take back my downvote, but it's too late.

Comment: In the end, it seems like the screen recordings that I was not finding -were just not getting saved. The reason why I wanted to find them so badly was because they were accidentally recorded, presumably for hours. So the recordings must be long and the files large, and unnecessary. However it seems like those accidental recordings were not being saved at all. Perhaps Apple recognizes them as accidental and doesn't save them. ‍♂️